# Como obter a instância do objeto superior/pai em uma function javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estou implementando uma biblioteca de extensão de métodos do `prototype`, e se faço da forma simples tudo funciona perfeitamente como podem verificar no simples exemplo a seguir:

```js
String.prototype.append = function(value) {
  // aqui o this é a instancia da String. Ok!
  return this.toString() + value;
};

document.getElementById('result').textContent = "Concatena com ".append("isto!");
```

```html
<p id="result">
</p>
```

Mas para evitar sobrescrever métodos do `prototype`, criei um objeto dentro do `prototype` para registrar esses métodos, mas com isso o escopo do método se modifica e o `this` não é mais uma referencia para a `String`, como pode ser verificado no exemplo a seguir:

```js
String.prototype.extencion = {
  append: function(value) {
    // aqui o this não é mas uma instancia da String. Fail =(!
    // Como pegar a instancia do objecto pai?
    return this.toString() + value;
  }
};

document.getElementById('result').textContent = "Concatena com ".extencion.append("isto!");
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

**Pergunta**

**É possível recuperar a instância do objeto pai em uma `function` no objeto filho?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Infelizmente isso que você quer não é possível. O objeto que você criou é um membro do protótipo de `String`, então o máximo que você poderia (embora eu acredite que nem isso seja possível) seria obter uma referência a esse protótipo - mas não à string que originou o acesso a ele. Pois uma vez que se subiu a cadeia de protótipos no acesso ao campo:

```
"Concatena com ".extencion
```

Já se perdeu a referência pra string original para sempre...

No caso dos métodos a referência ainda existe na forma do `this`, mas não no acesso a campos, de modo que eu costumo usar *closures* quando preciso fazer algo desse tipo (embora não saiba se é uma boa ideia mesmo fazer isso ou não). Exemplo:

```js
String.prototype.extencion = function() {
  return {
    append: (function(value) {
      return this.toString() + value;
    }).bind(this) // aqui o this é amarrado com o objeto original
  };
};

document.getElementById('result').textContent = "Concatena com ".extencion().append("isto!");
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Uma desvantagem desse método é que ele cria um objeto novo a cada invocação de função... Você poderia salvá-la para cada instância, mas aí há um desperdício de memória que pode se tornar significativo (dependendo do modo como se usa). Por isso disse não saber se é uma boa ideia. Um meio termo - não tão conveniente, mas sem os problemas citados acima - é fazer no "estilo jQuery":

```js
var extensoesString = {
  append: function(_, value) {
    return this.toString() + value;
  }
};

String.prototype.extencion = function(funcao) {
  return extensoesString[funcao].apply(this, arguments);
};

document.getElementById('result').textContent = "Concatena com ".extencion("append", "isto!");
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: bind functionará para todos os browser majoritários ? ie, chrome, edge, opera, safari, godzilla ? Em alguns casos teria que criar no início do script não? veja [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari e IE9+ pelo menos ([há um *polyfill* pros que não suportam](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)). O que é "edge" e "godzilla"?

Comment: Edge é o novo browser da microsoft (Pelo visto você ainda não instalou o Windows 10). [Godzila](https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130921200023AAdqRGa) é o mozzila firefox

Comment: @Fernando Eu queria apenas chamar atenção ao nome da função: O correto seria extension se estiver em inglês

Comment: Essa ultima edição matou a minha resposta :P  agora vou ter de inventar outra abordagem :) `+1`

Comment: @mgibsonbr, são boas formas de se fazer +1! Mas a primeira forma com _closures_ como você citou irá criar uma nova instância a cada chamada, o que não é bom, já a segunda a chamada se torna pouco intuitiva, ainda mais para uma biblioteca de extensão! Vou reanalisar meu problema!

Comment: @mgibsonbr, a respeito do `innerText` para `textContent`, alterei na pergunta também, assim fica coerente com a resposta e funciona no FF, não tinha reparado isto!

Comment: @Fernando hehe você pode tentar usar a criatividade, tipo criar uma cache (principalmente agora que os principais *browsers* [começaram a dar suporte ao `WeakMap`](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-WeakMap)) e só criar uma instância se ela não existir ainda, etc. Se compensa ou não, não sei, eu já me acostumei com o "jeito jQuery" rsrs.

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound, foi um erro de digitação, vou corrigir em meu projeto! Mas na pergunta vou deixar assim mesmo para não causar incoerência com a resposta! Obrigado!

Comment: @Fernando Recriar o objeto é irrelevante na maioria dos casos. Não se preocupe em otimizações a não ser que tenha um gargalo nessa parte. Eu faria o mais simples e legível, primeiro. Até onde sei, concatenar a string também cria uma nova instâcia, não ?

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound Em tese eu concordo com você (em particular se o compilador for esperto, e o coletor de lixo for generacional, o *overhead* da criação do objeto será mínimo), na prática, só testando... :)

Comment: Acho que em ES6 acho que daria para usar um [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), e interceptar a busca do método no objeto no momento da chamada.

Comment: @bfavaretto De fato, mas pelo que eu entendi essa solução sofreria dos mesmos problemas do meu primeiro exemplo (além do óbvio inconveniente de se ter que criar o Proxy). A menos que eu tenha entendido errado, é claro, não quer postar uma resposta com sua sugestão?

Comment: Eu preciso pesquisar pra ver como faz, se der certo eu posto depois. Também não tenho certeza se não sofreria dos mesmos problemas que você citou.

Comment: @bfavaretto, interessante sua sugestão, apesar de ser "_futurística_" =D, [já que até o momento somente o Firefox e o Edge tem isso implementado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#Browser_compatibility). Não consegui assimilar bem como isso iria ser implementado com [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), mas parece algo no minimo interessante. Se conseguir implementar um exemplo simplório de sua ideia seria agregador. (fiquei curioso =D)

Comment: @mgibsonbr, acabei implementando sua solução numero 1 (apesar de seus problemas, hehe), então vou aceitar está como resposta, pelo menos até ter solução melhor, talvez o [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) que o bfavaretto citou, mas possivelmente vai demorar para ser compatível e usual, já que nem há um _**Polyfill**_ para ele. hehe

Answer (score 4):

Podes criar um *Type* paralelo (`superString` no exemplo em baixo) e colocar os teus métodos alí. Para isso copias o prototype de String e passas as tuas strings pelo novo Type que crias-te. A ideia é assim:

```
var superString = (function () {
    // constructor
    function MyString(str) {
        this._str = str;
    }

    // criar uma cópia para não escrever métodos na String nativa
    MyString.prototype = Object.create(String.prototype);

    // funcionalidade "append"
    MyString.prototype.append = function (value) {
        return this.toString() + value;
    };

    // é preciso sobreescrever estes métodos... 
    MyString.prototype.toString = function () {
        return this._str;
    };

    MyString.prototype.valueOf = function () {
        return this._str;
    };

    Object.defineProperty(MyString.prototype, 'comprimento', {
        get: function () {
            return this._str.length;
        }
    });
    return MyString;
})();


var str = new superString('Concatena com ');

document.getElementById('result').textContent = str.append('isto!');
console.log(str.comprimento); // 14
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f2gzm6dx/

Algumas notas:

- Tive de re-escrever os métodos nativos `.valueOf ()` e `.toString ()` para funcionar senão dava erro.
- para re-criar uma propriedade tipo `.length` é teoréticamente possivel, mas o Chrome entra num loop infinito, assim criei uma propriedade `comprimento` com um *getter* para dar o que é esperado.

Outra solução usando a mesma ideia, sem importar o prototype de String já permitiria a propriedade `.length` e seria mais simples:

```
var superString = (function () {
    // constructor
    function MyString(str) {
        this._str = str;
    }

    // funcionalidade "append"
    MyString.prototype.append = function (value) {
        return this._str.toString() + value;
    };

    Object.defineProperty(MyString.prototype, 'length', {
        get: function () {
            return this._str.length;
        }
    });
    return MyString;
})();


var str = new superString('Concatena com ');

document.getElementById('result').textContent = str.append('isto!');
console.log(str.length); // 14
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93xc49Lm/

Comment: Boa e inteligente alternativa @Sergio. Ainda mais pelo fato de não sobrescrever nada diretamente na `String` nativa. +1

Comment: Gostei da abordagem +1, mas francamente não a usaria.